# ASP.net API 500 Internal Error When Using Async Await When the Process is still going

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a web API controller built on async await patter which calls external APIs, which takes 1 hour at times, the API is returning 500 Internal Server Error with Content-lenght Message. But the processing is going on in the background successfully, how do i avoid the 500 error and have it wait as long as the response comes, On the client side i have configure httpclient timeout to 2 hours. This is how my controller looks, any help is appreciated.

````
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessTestChange(string date, int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _bckendService.ProcessTestChange(date, ID);
                var response = EncapsulateResult(result, result == null ? System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound : result == 1 ? System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK : System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, string.Empty);
                
                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.TrackException(ex);
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Web servers should not be making a client wait for an hour or more for an HTTP response. There's a lot of network devices (firewalls, routers, proxies, etc.) between the client and server that could time out, because nobody does that.  I suggest you provide an API call for starting the task and another API call to check if it's finished. The client can poll.

Comment: While it might be possible to use chuncked encoding and stream unbuffered results over a long period, maybe you should use a websocket instead.

Comment: yes i would have to return 202 and later check on the status, the issue is with the way i'm deploying on azure app service which has a timeout set to 230 seconds

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following to keep a HttpClient connection alive:

```
    System.Net.ServicePoint servicePoint = System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(url);
    if (servicePoint != null) servicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 60000, 60000);
```

see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.settcpkeepalive?view=net-5.0